# Evernote Initial Sync Boost

Tags: synchronization, evernote, rate-limiting

I'm working on an application that requires completely syncing a users Evernote account, however on some larger account we run into rate limits. According to the API documentation there is a feature known as Initial Sync Boost, however I can not find any information on how to implement this other than -

> "You may request this when your key is created or when you are
>   activating your API key in our production environment"

When looking at creating a token sync boost is not listed as one of the parameters.

Can anyone clarify this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to implement anything on your side. When you activate your key on the production environment on [this page](https://dev.evernote.com/support/), you can request the initial sync boost so the support increase the limit for the initial sync for your key.

Comment: Ah, thank you for clearing that up! Muchly appreciated!